# Spring Data JPA - how to implement proper exception handling?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA to process database calls. For this purpose, I have created:

1. An EmployeeRepository interface, which extends a `JpaRepository<Employee, Long>`
2. An EmployeeService, which defines three methods:

   ```
    Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee);
    Optional<Employee> getEmployee(Long id);
    Long deleteEmployee(Long id);
   ```
3. An implementation of the EmployeeService:

   ```
    @Override
    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Employee> getEmployee(Long id) {
        return employeeRepository.findEmployeeById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Long deleteEmployee(Long id) {
        employeeRepository.deleteById(id);
        return id;
    }
   ```

The issue is the following:

The get-methods work fine and can return an optional. The save-method, on the other hand, cannot return an optional. Apparently the JpaRepository returns an instance of the saved object upon calling save(). I would rather return an optional, since something could go wrong when saving the employee and in that case, I would like to throw an error - i.e. whenever the optional is not present, I throw an error.

The same holds for the delete-operation: What, for example, if I ask to delete an employee and pass in an id, which does not exist? I would like to catch this error and only then return the passed in id, if the delete operation was successfull. Which error would I have to catch for this purpose? Can someone explain this to me?

=================================================

update:

- I have fixed the problem with the delete-call by simply checking if the given employee-id exists before calling `deleteById(id); if it doesn't, the service returns null, if it does, it return the id. The controller looks like this:

  ```
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Long> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Long deletedEmployeeId = employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
        if (deletedEmployeeId != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(deletedEmployeeId);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  ```

I am missing the DataAccessException, however. So, can it be that I would actually have to do the following:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Long> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            Long deletedEmployeeId = employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
            if (deletedEmployeeId != null) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(deletedEmployeeId);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
         } catch (DataAccessException e) {
             return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
         }
```

This looks a bit like an over-kill to be honest.

- I am still a bit unsure how to deal with the save-call. Before I posted this question, my controller was simply doing the following:

  ```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.saveEmployee(employee));
    }
  ```

What happens, if `employeeService.saveEmployee(employee)` throws a DataAccessException? Am I still returning a HTTP-status-code of 200, as I wrap the response in an `ResponseEntity.ok()` ?

If so, I would suggest to do the following:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        try {
            Employee savedEmployee = employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(savedEmployee);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Is this something people do? Or are DataAccessExceptions usually neglected as they are not expected?

Comment: When it comes to save() Optional means an object may exist and does not focus on db constraints.  For delete() JPA returns void

Comment: Did you try this,  @Override
 public Optional<Employee> saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
     return Optional.ofNullable(employeeRepository.save(employee));
 }

Comment: For the last question, if that's something people do: I do not bother about it. When your entity cannot be persisted an error will be thrown. In your last example you catch the exception and produce a response status 500, but that is what Spring would do on its own anyways, when the exception is not handled by your code. There are situations where you really want to handle exceptions, for a simple REST controller I don't see a benefit. (Except you want to produce a "readable" error message for any reason).

Comment: @SimonOelerich thx for your comment! So, would you suggest to just go with the second last example, just as it was originally? In this case, am I not returning an http status of 200 every time, even if a DataAccessException occurs (due to the ResponseEntity.ok()) ?

Comment: Yes, simply returning `ResponseEntity.ok(emplyeeRepo.findById(id))` is sufficient. For all save/find/delete it is fine. And most likely you won't need the service in addition to the repository. You can directly call the JpaRepository methods, as the exception handling is done by spring independent of its origin. You would only need it if there is additional business logic beyond simple bean validation.

Answer (score 1):

The method "save" always returns you the same object you are going to save. Only by checking the "id", you can see if the object is saved or not. But if an error occurs in the database, an exception will be thrown and you can catch it by putting "employeeRepository.save(employee)" in a try-catch block. The same way you can do for deleteById

Comment: Is it a `DataAccessException` that I would have to catch? Would you recommend to do this?

Comment: I always simply use "catch (exception e)". But I've also read that all the JPA exceptions will be converted to DataAccessException. You can catch the DataAccessException in the first catch "catch (exception e1)" and if anything else is thrown, catch in in a second catch "catch (exception e2)" as a tolerance.

Comment: allright, thx a lot, once again! I have updated my question, could you please take a look and let me know if that is what you had in mind?

Comment: Considering that an exception occurs if anything goes anything wrong during delete method in repository class, You will never enter "else" in your deleteEmployee of  the controller. I suggest you to refactor the part in your service layer  to the following code and then remove try-catch block in your controller:

Comment: public Long deleteEmployeeIU(Long id) {
        try {
            userRepository.deleteById(id);
            return id;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            return Long.valueOf(0);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to capture any error that might occur while inserting, updating or deleting data. I have adapted my code as indicated by Azadi Yazdani, I implemented the exception in the services layer and it worked as I wanted, thanks Azadi Yazdani.

```
@Service
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements UsuarioService {
    @Autowired
    UsuarioRepository repository;
    @Override
    public long grabar(Usuario usuario) {
        long result =0;
        try {
            Usuario u=repository.save(usuario);
            result=u.getId_usuario();
        }catch (DataAccessException e){
            result=-1;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```